# How can I solve "Duplicated key"?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, web

After npm run serve↓[image]

52:7  error  Duplicated key 'order'  vue/no-dupe-keys

I am now trying to illustrate only {order.id}, but this is the fist time to use Vue.js, therefore I am not sure how to fix it.
Also, my final achievement would be each column has {{item.image}},{{item.price}},{{item.qty}},{{item.amount}}.

OverDetailVue

```js
<template>
<div class="OrderListing">
  <h2>Order Detail</h2>
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>qty</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>

    <tr v-for="order in this.orders" :key="order.id">
      <td>{{ order.price }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.qty }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.total }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <tr class="total-row">
    <td>TOTAL:</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>{{ total }}</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>


</div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: 'OrderListing',
  computed: {
    items: function() {
      return this.$root.$data.cart.items || [];
    },
    total: function() {
      let sum = 0
      for (const item of this.items) {
        sum += item.total
      }
      return sum
    }
  },
  props: {
    order: Object
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      order: {}
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get("https://euas.person.ee/orders/" + this.$route.params.orderId)
      .then(response => {
        this.orders = response.data;
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }
}
</script>


<style scoped>
.option-image {
  max-height: 75px;
  max-width: 150px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: In `orders` check if any `order` id is repeated or not. id needs to be distinct here and should not repeat.

Comment: `order` is defined in data and also in template

Comment: So, you mean should I delete order of template or order of data?

Comment: Yeah, just choose one and use a different name.  As it is now, if you were to use `order` inside the `v-for`, the template couldn't know whether you mean `order` from the data property or `order` from the `v-for`.  Maybe you thought you had to declare the loop variable ahead of time, but you don't (can't).  Also don't use `this.orders` in the template, just use `orders`.  Oh you also have a prop named `order`.  That's 3 places you've declared the same variable, so there's going to be a clash.  Not sure what you're going for there but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
<template>
<div class="OrderListing">
  <h2>Order Detail</h2>
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>qty</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>

    <tr v-for="(item, index) in this.order.items" :key="item.productId + '_' + index">
      <td>
        <img :src="item.optionImage" class="option-image" />
      </td>
      <td>{{ item.price }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.qty }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.total }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="total-row">
      <td>TOTAL:</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>{{ total }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>



</div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: 'OrderListing',
  computed: {
    items: function() {
      return this.$root.$data.cart.items || [];
    },
    total: function() {
      let sum = 0
      for (const item of this.items) {
        sum += item.total
      }
      return sum
    }
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      order:{}
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get("https://euas.person.ee/user/orders/" + this.$route.params.orderId)
      .then(response => {
        this.order = response.data;
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }
}
</script>


<style scoped>
.option-image {
  max-height: 75px;
  max-width: 150px;
}
</style>
```